# Недопустимое имя объекта

Tags: sql, sql-server

Необходимо получить Supplier.Name вес всех товаров которого максимальный.

```
SELECT Name 
    FROM (
            SELECT Name, SUM(Weight) AS Sum_weight
            FROM Supplier S, Product P, P_S_Connect PS 
            WHERE S.SupplierID=PS.SupplierID AND P.ProductID=PS.ProductID
            GROUP BY Name
          ) NewTable
    WHERE Sum_weight=(SELECT MAX(Sum_weight) FROM NewTable);
```

Выдает ошибку

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 31 Недопустимое имя объекта
>   "NewTable".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NewTable это алиас выборки в конкретном запросе, к нему нельзя обращаться еще раз как к таблице.

Можно сделать например так, используя CTE:

```
WITH NewTable(Name,Sum_weight) as(
     SELECT Name, SUM(Weight)
       FROM Supplier S, Product P, P_S_Connect PS 
      WHERE S.SupplierID=PS.SupplierID AND P.ProductID=PS.ProductID
      GROUP BY Name
)
SELECT Name 
  FROM NewTable
 WHERE Sum_weight=(SELECT MAX(Sum_weight) FROM NewTable);
```

Или так, используя оконные функции:

```
SELECT Name FROM (
    SELECT Name, Sum_weight,
           MAX(Sum_weight) over() as Max_weight
      FROM (
        SELECT Name, SUM(Weight) AS Sum_weight
          FROM Supplier S, Product P, P_S_Connect PS 
         WHERE S.SupplierID=PS.SupplierID AND P.ProductID=PS.ProductID
         GROUP BY Name
      ) A
   ) A
  WHERE Sum_weight=Max_weight
```

А на стандартном SQL, без расширений типа CTE или оконных функций боюсь только так:

```
SELECT Name
  FROM Supplier S, Product P, P_S_Connect PS 
 WHERE S.SupplierID=PS.SupplierID AND P.ProductID=PS.ProductID
 GROUP BY Name
HAVING SUM(Weight)=
 (
  SELECT MAX(Sum_weight)
    FROM (
      SELECT SUM(Weight) AS Sum_weight
        FROM Supplier S, Product P, P_S_Connect PS 
       WHERE S.SupplierID=PS.SupplierID AND P.ProductID=PS.ProductID
       GROUP BY Name
    ) A
 )
```

Comment: Спасибо, не знал. Но возможно ли сделать это запросом с подзапросом?

Comment: @Viktor В принципе можно, но тогда вам в подзапросе придется полностью повторить сам запрос, сослаться никак не получится

Comment: Получается, что необходимо именовать таблицу, которая создается в подзапросе? Ведь без этого алиаса выдает ошибку Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 61
Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции ")".

Comment: @Viktor В MS Sql да, алиас у выборки в from должен быть. Часть других СУБД без этого обходятся

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решена.

Answer (score 2):

На будущее., порядок выполнения любого запроса:
From --> Where -->  Group by --> Having --> Select --> Order by

Comment: Оно конечно так, Но как это поможет пониманию сути проблемы. Если идти по такой цепочке, то логика лично мне подсказала бы: "первым выполнился from основного запроса, значит в where уже можно пользоваться именем NewTable", и да, им там действительно можно пользоваться, но ведь только не в подзапросах в качестве таблицы